# Simulation of Kinect on Husky Robot

Tags: ros, kinect, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm new to ROS and have gone through the basic tutorials. I'm trying to get gmapping working on the husky robot in simulation. I want to simulate gmapping using a kinect (which I will be using on later in real life if the simulation works). Right now I have the kinect showing up in gazebo but I don't have anything coming up in rviz (no topics - that i can see).

From what I have gathered from reading online is that I need to modify the base.urdf.xacro file. Can anyone help me and tell me what exactly I need to do to get simulated kinect data, so that I can progress towards mapping a room?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201796/simulation-of-kinect-on-husky-robot/) by [musiqsoulchild](https://answers.ros.org/users/21484/musiqsoulchild/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [richardsondynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/25769/richardsondynamics/) on 2016-01-28**:
were you able to setup the kinect on the husky, Im using the jackal which is similat and I run into the same problem. How did you set up the kinect on the gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look into the [turtlebot_description](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_description) package, which contains the files for simulated kinect. Get rid of the turtlebot robot description and use the part which contains the kinect.  It should be easy to copy the code for the husky robot. Also look into the [turtlebot_gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo) package which details the simulation of the turtlebot in an empty world.

You can use the launch file as

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo  turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

Simulated kinect topic is published on the `/camera /image_raw` topic and to get the point cloud is available at `/camera/depth/points` topic. Look into the [turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_gazebo.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/indigo/turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_gazebo.urdf.xacro) from which you can simulate the kinect.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2